# Socket Creation in case client is IPV4 and server is IPV6

Tags: c++, sockets, httpclient

During socket creation we will be making use of INET in case if IP address is IPv4 and INET6 incase of IPV6. During binding and connect operation we will make use of Strut sock_addrin for IPv4 and sock_sddrin6 for IPv6.

In my case client is IPV4 and server is IPv6 , the server supports dual stack operation so I think I can connect to server. Please inform if its not possible?

So while creating socket I need to use INET or INET6? Similar doubts on bind and connect. Which structures I need to make use of.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16482003/760746). When your server supports dual stack you should use its IPv4 address to connect to it from IPv4 clients.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting IPv4 client to IPv6 server: connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480729/connecting-ipv4-client-to-ipv6-server-connection-refused)