# Winsock2 C++: How do I find the address for an IPv4 client to send a packet to an IPv6 server?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, ipv6, ipv4

I have been trying to set up a UDP server using IPv6 that accepts packets from IPv4 and IPv6 clients. I am programming using winsock2 in C++ with Codeblocks in Windows. I have successfully received and bounced back a packet from IPv6 from a friend. I can also receive and bounce back packets from myself through IPv4 when I send to a local address of 10.0.0.90 (static) and 127.0.0.1 (loopback). Obviously, when a friend on a different network tries to send to those local addresses through the internet, no packets are received on my end. **Where do I find an IPv4 address so that an IPv4-only client can successfully sendto() to my IPv6 server through the internet?**

When I ping myself through getaddrinfo() at 127.0.0.1, the resulting addrinfo struct contains a blank wildcard ipv4 address (0.0.0.0) and no ipv6 addresses.

When I ping myself through my IPv6 address using getaddrinfo(), I get only one ipv6 addrinfo struct with the same IPv6 address and no IPv4 struct.

When I call getaddrinfo() with a NULL value for the destination, I get two addrinfo structs both containing the wildcard values of IPv4 and IPv6 locations.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480729/connecting-ipv4-client-to-ipv6-server-connection-refused), I have gathered that to connect to an IPv6 server with an ipv4 client, you use an ipv4 mapped ipv6 address. My problem is that I'm not sure if I even have an ipv4 address anymore. When I go to www.whatismyipaddress.com, I get only an ipv6 public address.

None of these trials provided me with an ipv4 address that I could give to an ipv4-only client and now I'm utterly stuck. I have already dealt with binding to a wildcard IP, and disabling IPV6_V6ONLY. Everything works pretty well, but I have no idea where else left to look for a destination address. Could someone please provide me a hint into the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: When calling `getaddrinfo()`, specify your machine's actual network hostname, not an IP or NULL, and be sure to set the hints family to `AF_UNSPEC` so you can get both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination address is the IPv4 address of your server. With V6ONLY disabled your IPv6 socket can receive IPv4 packets, but your server still needs to have a reachable IPv4 address. Without an IPv4 address IPv4-only clients can't reach you.

IPv4 mapped IPv6 addresses are just to represent IPv4 addresses in IPv6 software. But you still need an IPv4 address.

Comment: Hi Sander, I found this website that gave me an IPv4 address. Does this mean I have an IPv4 public address? I tried using the IPv4 address listed on the website, but I never receive a packet. Or since my ipconfig does not list an IPv4 address, I am limited to only IPv6 connections?

Sorry forgot to list the website http://ip4.me/

Comment: If your ifconfig doesn't list am IPv4 address then you are probably behind a NAT64 and you don't have an IPv4 address. Sorry, you won't be able to receive incoming IPv4 connections then.

Comment: If your server is behind a NAT/router, you need to enable its port forwarding feature so inbound connections on a designated public IP/port can be routed to your server's listening IP/port.

Comment: The chances that whoever runs that NAT64 gateway allows this is very very small though

Comment: I contacted my ISP and they provided me with an IPv4 address. My friends can ping me through that address but I always get timed out pinging myself. My ip config lists a local address of 10.0.0.90 instead of the public one though.  I'll have to work through the problem from the beginning again and try to get things working. Thanks for the help everyone.